# Constructor for null and undefined

Tags: javascript

Of the five primitive JavaScript data types (`string`, `number`, `boolean`, `null` and `undefined`), the first three have associated constructors:

```
new String("Hello!")
new Number(40)
new Boolean(true)
```

The constructed objects are wrappers for the object literals. In particular, `new String("Hello!") === "Hello!"` evaluates to `false`.

Are there a similar constructors for the `null` and `undefined` primitive data types that produce object wrappers different from the corresponding object literal?

Comment: I don't think you can have a constructor for undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there are not, and it wouldn't make sense considering the "values" they represent.

Ignore the fact that typeof null === 'object'

[According to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String):

```
JavaScript automatically converts primitives and String objects, so that it's
possible to use String object methods for primitive strings.
```

The interpreter just does some magical auto-wrapping of primitive in classes if you call a method that affects the primitive, like `charAt`.

Comment: When people ask "Why is `typeof null == 'object'` and I say "because ECMA-262 says so" I get criticised. But I have no other explanation.

Answer (score 0):

primitive types dont have constructors. string, number and boolean have Object wrappers that wrap the primitive type. Thats why the String Object in js is not the same as a "" as you stated. The null and undefined primitive types dont have an associated Object constructor.

Comment: While all Functions are Objects, not all Objects can be constructors. Only Function objects can be constructors.